# Laravel Eloquent multiple sums

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Columns of contact table

```
Name=client_id
Name=room_id
Name=stats - a number
Name=date
```

I need to calculate stats for a year, per weekly basis, monthly, and quaterly, many sums of the stats column. I made this SQL for the older system, now I need to get the sum the stats column, not count them like before.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    date > '2021-01-11 00:00:00' 
    AND date < '2021-01-18 00:00:00' 
    AND room_id = 6 
    AND client_id = 1
  ) as week1,
  SUM(
    date > '2021-12-20 00:00:00' 
    AND date < '2021-12-27 00:00:00' 
    AND room_id = 6 
    AND client_id = 1
  ) as week51, 
  SUM(
    date > '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
    AND date < '2021-01-31 23:59:00' 
    AND room_id = 6 
    AND client_id = 1
  ) as month1, 
  SUM(
    date > '2021-12-01 00:00:00' 
    AND date < '2021-12-31 23:59:00' 
    AND room_id = 6 
    AND client_id = 1
  ) as month12 
FROM 
  contact;
```

Is is possible to do it with Eloquent, or I need to use DB facade? If it's an easier way to do it with Eloquent, i'd like to use it.

Comment: You need to group the records by ```month``` or ```week```

Comment: And please provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
$conditions  = [
  
    'week1' =>  [
    
        ['date' ,  '>' ,  '2021-01-11 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['date' ,  '<' ,  '2021-01-18 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['room_id' ,  6 ] ,     
        ['client_id' ,  1 ] ,     

    ] , 
    'month1' =>  [
    
        ['date' ,  '>' ,  '2021-12-01 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['date' ,  '<' ,  '2021-01-31 23:59:00' ] ,     
        ['room_id' ,  6 ] ,     
        ['client_id' ,  1 ] ,     

    ] , 
  
  ];

  $output = [];
  foreach ($conditions as $k=>$condition )
      $output[$k] = Contact::where($condition)->sum('stats');
```

---------------- using union -----------------

```
$conditions  = [
  
    'week1' =>  [
    
        ['date' ,  '>' ,  '2021-01-11 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['date' ,  '<' ,  '2021-01-18 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['room_id' ,  6 ] ,     
        ['client_id' ,  1 ] ,     

    ] , 
    'month1' =>  [
    
        ['date' ,  '>' ,  '2021-12-01 00:00:00' ] ,     
        ['date' ,  '<' ,  '2021-01-31 23:59:00' ] ,     
        ['room_id' ,  6 ] ,     
        ['client_id' ,  1 ] ,     

    ] , 
  
];

$base_query = false ;
foreach ($conditions as $k=>$condition )
{
    $query = Contact::selectRaw("SUM(stats) as total , '$k' as 'title'   ")->where($condition) ;
    if($base_query === false )
        $base_query = $query ;
    else
        $base_query->union($query);
}

$results = $base_query->get() ;

   foreach ($results as $result )
   {
       dump($result->title , $result->total );
   }
```

Comment: What makes you think they don't mean `SUM()`? I think they want to sum the `stats` column.

Comment: @miken32 yeah my bad , i was looking at the query and didnt see the sum column ... should have red the description

Comment: @hretic It is correct, but this runs multiple queries, I would like just one statement. I did come up with something like `$client->stats->where('room_id', 6)->whereBetween('date', ['2021-11-19', '2021-11-20'])->sum('stats')` but this needs to be ran multiple times.

Comment: @AlexandruPopa so i guess you can use `union` or some sort of `subquery` if possible ... i've added union solution to my answer